# OS detection with Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno

I've been searching for a bit, and feel like it's impossible, but I will ask anyway: is it possible for an Arduino to detect what OS it uses, like how a rubber ducky does via USB?

I want specific code to run when it's plugged in a different operating system.

Is there any possible way to do that?

I've tried to find libraries for it, or any other stuff, but I can't seem to find any.

Comment: Not sure, how a rubber ducky does it, though it will definitely will be by a clever use of the USB protocol. With the Uno that would only work, if you hack the USB-Serial chip (Atmega32u4 I believe), which handles the USB connection for the Uno.

Comment: According to the Rubber Ducky’s Web site, it uses passive OS fingerprinting. You may try [FingerprintUSBHost](https://github.com/keyboardio/FingerprintUSBHost) on a Leonardo or similar USB-enabled Arduino (not an Uno).